# How to check a set of lines in a text file for patterns using awk, sed, or grep?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I wish to write a bash script that will read a file containing 100s of lines and look for the pattern `def <space>`, if this pattern is found in the line, it will check the next line to see if the pattern `'''` is present in this next line. If yes, then it checks if the next `'''` is encountered 5 lines away. If all of these are yes, echo TRUE, else echo FALSE.

For example, file 1:

```
line 1
line2
...

    def something...
        '''
        random text
        rand..text
        rand..
        ra..


        '''
```

echoes TRUE

File 2:

```
line 1
line 2
...

    def something..
        int a
        ...
```

echoes FALSE

There can be multiple such `def <space>` patterns within the file and if any of them fails the test, the overall result is FALSE.

How do I do this using `awk`, `grep`, or `sed`?

Comment: You could do this with a complex and fragile shell script, but since you're working with Python, it would likely be easier to do this with pure python. You could, for instance, iterate over the functions defined in the current scope and inspect their docstrings.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But we are testing student codes on a third-party environment which lets us create test cases using bash only.

Comment: `bash` is not a text processing tool, just so you know.

Comment: You're testing student code and you want to check if their code has 5-line docstrings? Without knowing much more about your situation, this sounds like an ineffective test of students' Python knowledge to me.

Comment: Since you're using bash, could you write a Python script that contains the test cases and then call `python -c 'inline script here'` or `python /path/to/script`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, will explain if this is what you're looking for.

```
 grep -A5 "def " file.txt | grep -n "'''" | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ' | awk  '{if ($1 == "2" && $2 == "" ) print "TRUE";else print "FALSE"}'
```